# Laravel, need variable on admin routes

Tags: laravel-5

I need a variable for my admin dashboard, so my guess is to put something inside cache so I can do I can access it in my admin layout-template.
I need to merge 2 config files with links:

```
$dashboard_links = \Auth::user()->hasRole(['root', 'admin'])
    ? config('dashboard')
    : config('dashboard-user');
$taxonomies = Config::get('taxonomies');

foreach ($taxonomies as $name => $config)
{
    $original_array = array_splice( $dashboard_links, $config['order'], 0 );
    $dashboard_links = array_merge ($original_array, [$name => $config], $dashboard_links); 
}
```

I want the `$dashboard_links` available in the base template "resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php".
But I don't want to create the variable on each page request or put it in every controller. It's only needed when someone is logged as an administrator and visits any admin page.
I am not that good in programming so I don't know what is the best approach.
These are my routes if helpfull:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function()
{
    // edit post form
    Route::get('post/edit/{slug}', [
        'as'    => 'post-edit',
        'uses'  => 'Post\AdminController@edit'
    ]);

        Route::get('medialibrary/edit/{id}', [
        'as'    => 'media-edit',
        'uses'  => 'MediaLibrary\MediaController@edit',
    ])->where('id', '[0-9]+');

    // and so on...
});
```

Comment: I think you should have to implement this on role based. Something like user role.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to help. Are you talking about a variable which is required on every page request to the admin? How is the variable value created? And no you shouldn't use the cache unless the value is completely transient.

Comment: @Joe I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a view composer https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers

View composers allow you to pass variables to all views associated with the composer.

So you would register a new service provider to associate your composer to specific routes. Then in your composer poplate the variable, and pass it to all admin views.

Comment: thank you, this is what I need. thanks to your answer I found a nice example here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passing-array-to-master-layout-through-view-composer